# Найти arcctg(x)

Tags: c

Как посчитать arcctg(x)  на языке Си?

Comment: Вы не можете найти арктангенс?  `cin >> x;
    y = atan(x);
    cout << y;`

Comment: [atan()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atan.htm)

Comment: `arcctg(x)={x>0,atan(1/x) ; x<0,π+atan(1/x)}`

Answer (score 2):

Как я понимаю, Вам нужно найти арккотангенс. В сишной библиотеке `Math` нет функции арккотангенса, однако он связан со значением арктангенса следующим соотношением:

```
arcctg(x) = pi/2 - arctg(x)
```

Т.е. будет примерно так

```
const double pi = 3.14159265358979323846;
double y = pi/2 - atan(x); // получаем значение арккотангенса
```

Не стоит также забывать, что полученное значение `y` будет в радианах.

Comment: Извините за занудство, но в math.h определены константы M_PI и M_PIl. Так что рекомендуется пользоваться ими. А еще интернет предлагает вычислить в программе один раз число Пи как atan(1)*4 и пользоваться им.

Comment: Вообще насколько я знаю, константа `M_PI` не входит в стандарт языка C, а определяется в зависимости от реализации компилятора.

Comment: @pepsicoca1, `M_PI` — это из POSIX.